# PowerShell to map a drive with saved credentials doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, mapped-folder, network-drive

I thought I had fixed my solution:
Mapping SharePoint Drives without the need of 3rd party software or refreshing credentials every 2-3 days.

My code is the following:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

Install-Module -Name CredentialManager
Install-Module -Name CredentialManager -AcceptLicense -AllowClobber -Force -Verbose 

Import-Module -Name CredentialManager -Verbose
Import-MOdule -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Verbose
$Credential = Get-StoredCredential -Target 'O365'
$Site_URL = "https://SITE.sharepoint.com/sites/Company_Share/"

$Apply_Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.SharepointOnlineCredentials($Credential.UserName, $Credential.Password)
write-host $Credential.Password
write-host $Apply_Credentials


$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site_URL)
$Context.Credentials = $Apply_Credentials
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Site = $Context.Web;
$Context.Load($Site)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

MapDrive -Letter M -Path $Site_URL

Function MapDrive{   
  param($Letter,$Path)  
  try{
        $strLetter = $Letter + ':'
        net use $strLetter $Path /PERSISTENT:NO
        LogItem -LogEntry "$Letter has been mapped."}
  Catch{
        LogItem -LogEntry "$Letter failed to map."}
}
```

I have added the site to the trusted zone and disabled the 'security setting' in Internet Explorer. But sadly it still gets me the error 'you have no access... please browse the site and enable automatic log in.... .

What am I doing wrong however ? What's happening in the 3rd party software that I missed this time? Will I ever succeed in my objective?

Comment: With IE's impending deprecation in M365, I would not assume that functionality such as WebDAV will continue to work long term. Your best bet is to use the OneDrive sync client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly the OneDrive sync client will be difficult to implement due to the environment. i will continue my fight with SharePoint ;)

Comment: It might be that the 3rd party solutions open invisible IE browser windows and re-map the whole thing each time user logs in.